# POSTGRES Time without timezone comparison

Tags: postgresql, time, timezone

I am attempting to do the following:

I have a `TIME` column where I store a time without an offset. I also store a timezone column as a string in the format 'America/Chicago'.

The thought here, is that I can take the time column and do (`time_col AT TIME ZONE timezone`) and compare it to the `CURRENT_TIME` to determine whether it is greater than or less than to determine whether something should fire or not on the backend.

I cannot store the time with a timezone as this deals with a situation when something starts, and if daylight savings occurs it still starts at the same time. Storing with a timezone offset would cause it to be off by an hour if DT/ST switch occurs. Ex. Starts at 5:00PM America/Chicago. When daylight savings occurs, if stored with timezone, this is now 6:00PM America/Chicago, but should not be. It should still be 5:00PM even with the time switch. Thus, adding the offset on the fly prevents this.

However, the following does not seem to add any offset to the time at all:

```
SELECT time_col AS start_orig, (time_col AT TIME ZONE timezone) AS start_new, CURRENT_TIME as now_time FROM "time_test_table"
```

Regardless of what timezone is (I've tried just adding 'America/Chicago' and 'utc') the time does not change and does not appear with an offset.

For instance:

```
timezone         start_orig  start_new  now_time  
---------------  ----------  ---------  --------  
America/Chicago  19:00:00    19:00:00   16:49:50
```

I figured I'd get clever and switch the timezone of `CURRENT_TIME` to see if `AT TIME ZONE` functioned as the docs say, and it doesn't seem to:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIME AS now_time, (CURRENT_TIME AT TIME ZONE 'utc') AS utc_time, (CURRENT_TIME AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago') AS ct_time FROM "time_test_table"

now_time  utc_time  ct_time   
--------  --------  --------  
16:51:28  16:51:28  16:51:28
```

For reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-datetime.html

Has anyone dealt with `AT TIME ZONE` before? Where is my misunderstanding occurring here?

EDIT
Postgres version 9.4.6
Time column:

```
    TABLE_CAT   TABLE_SCHEM TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE   TYPE_NAME   COLUMN_SIZE BUFFER_LENGTH   DECIMAL_DIGITS  NUM_PREC_RADIX  NULLABLE    REMARKS COLUMN_DEF  SQL_DATA_TYPE   SQL_DATETIME_SUB    CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH   ORDINAL_POSITION    IS_NULLABLE SCOPE_CATLOG    SCOPE_SCHEMA    SCOPE_TABLE SOURCE_DATA_TYPE    IS_AUTOINCREMENT
    (null)  public  time_test_table time_col    92  time    15  (null)  6   10  1   (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  15  30  YES (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  NO
(null)  public  time_test_table timezone    12  varchar 255 (null)  0   10  1   (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  255 8   YES (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  NO
```

Comment: Please start with your version of Postgres and the exact table definition, so we see the *actual* data type in use.

Comment: I can't reproduce your results. See: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=02057b662a6d8236ea881a464d912377. Maybe your client has a finger in the pie?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Added my postgres version above and the specs for the two columns being used. Your fiddle seems to work, but running this queries (using db visualizer for this) doesn't seem to produce the same results.

Comment: May be an issue with your client displaying local times even for `time with time zone`. Else, the result of `time_col AT TIME ZONE timezone` should show a time offset for the `time with time zone` type. Related questions about `AT TIME ZONE`: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgres%5D+code%3A%22AT+TIME+ZONE%22

Comment: Hmm... i'm running this directly in DBVisualizer, so there's no self-built client. I would assume a db visualizer would just spit out what the db gave it, not extra formatting.